# Why arrayname [i] does not equal to *(arrayname + i) in this case in C++

Tags: c++

For the following code, why arrayname [i] does not equal to *(arrayname + i) in this case and the output can be strange：

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct fish
{
    char kind[10] = "abcd";
    int weight;
    float length;
};

int main()
{
    int numoffish;
    cout << "How many fishes?\n";
    cin >> numoffish;
    fish *pfish = new fish[numoffish];
    cout << pfish[0].kind << endl; //the output is "abcd"

    /*if the above code is changed to
    "cout << (*pfish.kind);"
     then compile error happens */

    /*and if the above code is changed to
    "cout << (*pfish->kind);"
    then the output is only an "a" instead of "abcd"*/

    delete [] pfish;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't match your question. You correctly state that `a[i]` is the same as `*(a+i)`.   Your code contains `pfish[0]`, which according to that rule is the same as `*(pfish + 0)`.  So far so good. But then your code sample contains `(*pfish.kind)` which is completely different to `*(pfish + 0)`.

Comment: @M.M Yes I see, thanks. I just did not realize that (*pfish.kind) is different with (*pfish).kind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.` operator and `->` operator have higher precedence than unary `*` operator.

You have to add parentheses to have `*` calculated before accessing members like

```
cout << ((*pfish).kind);
```

Answer (score 1):

(*pfish).kind is equal to pfish[0].kind

*pfish.kind is equal to *(pfish.kind), and pfish is of pointer type, so you need to use operator *->* on it rather than the operator *.* to access it's member, and so your compiler complained about it.

Also *pfish->kind is *(pfish->kind), pfish->kind is "abcd" of type char[10], so dereferencnig it is a char, it is equal to pfish->kind[0], so it only outputed 'a'.

C++ operator precedence: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence